# Azure Web Job sometimes cannot connect to storage account

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

We have an Azure Web Job that runs (with [Singleton] attribute) and it occasionally complains about not being able to connect to the storage account that it needs to aquire the lock or when we try to log to storage account.

In the web job logs, it will result in "Invalid storage account XXXXXX. Please make sure your credentials are correct."

I have double-checked the access keys for the storage account, and the values in the hosting Azure Service's connection strings for the AzureWebJobsStorage and AzureWebJobsDashboard and also for our own application setting that we use when trying to create a CloudTableClient for logging.

This is intermittent, and works about 80% of the time, and 20% time it complains.

Sample from logs:

```
    [12/02/2017 16:45:10 > d747a0: INFO] Singleton lock acquired (5d3cc9c4e92841579c4df47db66e5bfc/CHO.WebJobs.csRfid.GPOFunctions.ProcessQueueMessage)

[12/02/2017 16:45:10 > d747a0: INFO] 12/2/2017 4:45:10 PM - Rfid processing started for Message Id 3286783.

[12/02/2017 16:45:13 > d747a0: INFO] Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BrokeredMessage{MessageId:3286783}

[12/02/2017 16:45:13 > d747a0: INFO] 12/2/2017 4:45:13 PM - Rfid processing finished for Message Id 3286783.

[12/02/2017 16:45:13 > d747a0: INFO] Singleton lock released (5d3cc9c4e92841579c4df47db66e5bfc/CHO.WebJobs.csRfid.GPOFunctions.ProcessQueueMessage)

[12/02/2017 16:45:13 > d747a0: INFO] Executed 'GPOFunctions.ProcessQueueMessage' (Succeeded, Id=aa430942-4fcb-4fa6-a899-fe936a183494)

[12/02/2017 16:45:13 > d747a0: INFO] Executing 'GPOFunctions.ProcessQueueMessage' (Reason='New ServiceBus message detected on 'tprfid/Subscriptions/subRfidUat'.', Id=c6eb4e56-ebd0-4410-acde-4e3bd7c3666d)

[12/02/2017 16:45:13 > d747a0: INFO] Singleton lock acquired (5d3cc9c4e92841579c4df47db66e5bfc/CHO.WebJobs.csRfid.GPOFunctions.ProcessQueueMessage)

[12/02/2017 16:45:13 > d747a0: INFO] 12/2/2017 4:45:13 PM - Rfid processing started for Message Id 3286784.

[12/02/2017 16:45:16 > d747a0: INFO] Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BrokeredMessage{MessageId:3286784}

[12/02/2017 16:45:16 > d747a0: WARN] Reached maximum allowed output lines for this run, to see all of the job's logs you can enable website application diagnostics

[12/02/2017 16:55:03 > d747a0: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code -532462766

[12/02/2017 16:55:03 > d747a0: SYS INFO] Process went down, waiting for 0 seconds

[12/02/2017 16:55:03 > d747a0: SYS INFO] Status changed to PendingRestart

[12/02/2017 16:55:03 > d747a0: SYS INFO] Run script 'CHO.WebJobs.csRfid.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'

[12/02/2017 16:55:03 > d747a0: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running

[12/02/2017 16:55:11 > d747a0: INFO] Found the following functions:

[12/02/2017 16:55:11 > d747a0: INFO] CHO.WebJobs.csRfid.GPOFunctions.ProcessQueueMessage

[12/02/2017 16:55:11 > d747a0: INFO] CHO.WebJobs.csRfid.GPOFunctions.ProcessTimer

[12/02/2017 16:55:12 > d747a0: INFO] Singleton lock acquired (5d3cc9c4e92841579c4df47db66e5bfc/CHO.WebJobs.csRfid.GPOFunctions.ProcessTimer.Listener)

[12/02/2017 16:55:12 > d747a0: INFO] Executing 'GPOFunctions.ProcessQueueMessage' (Reason='New ServiceBus message detected on 'tprfid/Subscriptions/subRfidUat'.', Id=ac2385b9-2000-4533-9166-57df9fef904f)

[12/02/2017 16:55:12 > d747a0: INFO] Singleton lock acquired (5d3cc9c4e92841579c4df47db66e5bfc/CHO.WebJobs.csRfid.GPOFunctions.ProcessQueueMessage)

[12/02/2017 16:55:13 > d747a0: INFO] 12/2/2017 4:55:13 PM - Rfid processing started for Message Id 3286815.

[12/02/2017 16:55:42 > d747a0: ERR ] 

[12/02/2017 16:55:42 > d747a0: ERR ] Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

[12/02/2017 16:55:42 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)

[12/02/2017 16:55:42 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalBind(EndPoint localEP)

[12/02/2017 16:55:42 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnectEx(EndPoint remoteEP, Boolean flowContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)

[12/02/2017 16:55:42 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UnsafeBeginConnect(EndPoint remoteEP, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)

[12/02/2017 16:55:42 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)

[12/02/2017 16:55:42 > d747a0: ERR ]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

[12/02/2017 16:55:42 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

[12/02/2017 16:55:42 > d747a0: ERR ]    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndGetResponse[T](IAsyncResult getResponseResult) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line 284

[12/02/2017 16:55:42 > d747a0: ERR ]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

[12/02/2017 16:55:42 > d747a0: ERR ]    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndExecuteAsync[T](IAsyncResult result) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line 50

[12/02/2017 16:55:42 > d747a0: ERR ]    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue.CloudQueue.EndExists(IAsyncResult asyncResult) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Queue\CloudQueue.cs:line 994

[12/02/2017 16:55:42 > d747a0: ERR ]    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.AsyncExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1`1.<CreateCallback>b__0(IAsyncResult ar) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Util\AsyncExtensions.cs:line 66

[12/02/2017 16:55:42 > d747a0: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

[12/02/2017 16:55:42 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

[12/02/2017 16:55:42 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

[12/02/2017 16:55:42 > d747a0: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Queues.Listeners.QueueListener.<ExecuteAsync>d__21.MoveNext()

[12/02/2017 16:55:42 > d747a0: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

[12/02/2017 16:55:42 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

[12/02/2017 16:55:42 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

[12/02/2017 16:55:42 > d747a0: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Timers.TaskSeriesTimer.<RunAsync>d__14.MoveNext()

[12/02/2017 16:55:42 > d747a0: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

[12/02/2017 16:55:42 > d747a0: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Timers.WebJobsExceptionHandler.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<OnUnhandledExceptionAsync>b__0()

[12/02/2017 16:55:42 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)

[12/02/2017 16:55:42 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)

[12/02/2017 16:55:42 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)

[12/02/2017 16:55:42 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)

[12/02/2017 16:55:42 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

[12/02/2017 16:55:42 > d747a0: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code -532462766

[12/02/2017 16:55:42 > d747a0: SYS INFO] Process went down, waiting for 60 seconds

[12/02/2017 16:55:42 > d747a0: SYS INFO] Status changed to PendingRestart

[12/02/2017 17:03:44 > d747a0: SYS INFO] Run script 'CHO.WebJobs.csRfid.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'

[12/02/2017 17:03:44 > d747a0: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running

[12/02/2017 17:04:13 > d747a0: ERR ] 

[12/02/2017 17:04:13 > d747a0: ERR ] Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid storage account 'sachouat'. Please make sure your credentials are correct.

[12/02/2017 17:04:13 > d747a0: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.DefaultStorageCredentialsValidator.<ValidateCredentialsAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()

[12/02/2017 17:04:13 > d747a0: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

[12/02/2017 17:04:13 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

[12/02/2017 17:04:13 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

[12/02/2017 17:04:13 > d747a0: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.DefaultStorageCredentialsValidator.<ValidateCredentialsAsync>d__1.MoveNext()

[12/02/2017 17:04:13 > d747a0: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

[12/02/2017 17:04:13 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

[12/02/2017 17:04:13 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

[12/02/2017 17:04:13 > d747a0: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.DefaultStorageAccountProvider.<TryGetAccountAsync>d__23.MoveNext()

[12/02/2017 17:04:13 > d747a0: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

[12/02/2017 17:04:13 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

[12/02/2017 17:04:13 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

[12/02/2017 17:04:13 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)

[12/02/2017 17:04:13 > d747a0: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.JobHostContextFactory.<CreateAndLogHostStartedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()

[12/02/2017 17:04:13 > d747a0: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

[12/02/2017 17:04:13 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

[12/02/2017 17:04:13 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

[12/02/2017 17:04:13 > d747a0: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.JobHostContextFactory.<CreateAndLogHostStartedAsync>d__4.MoveNext()

[12/02/2017 17:04:13 > d747a0: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

[12/02/2017 17:04:13 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

[12/02/2017 17:04:13 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

[12/02/2017 17:04:13 > d747a0: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost.<CreateContextAndLogHostStartedAsync>d__44.MoveNext()

[12/02/2017 17:04:13 > d747a0: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

[12/02/2017 17:04:13 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

[12/02/2017 17:04:13 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

[12/02/2017 17:04:13 > d747a0: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost.<StartAsyncCore>d__27.MoveNext()

[12/02/2017 17:04:13 > d747a0: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

[12/02/2017 17:04:13 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

[12/02/2017 17:04:13 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

[12/02/2017 17:04:13 > d747a0: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost.Start()

[12/02/2017 17:04:13 > d747a0: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost.RunAndBlock()

[12/02/2017 17:04:13 > d747a0: ERR ]    at CHO.WebJobs.csRfid.ProcessRfidXml.StartListening() in F:\agent\_work\4\s\CHO.WebJobs\CHO.WebJobs.csRfid\ProcessRfidXml.cs:line 68

[12/02/2017 17:04:13 > d747a0: ERR ]    at CHO.WebJobs.csRfid.Program.Main() in F:\agent\_work\4\s\CHO.WebJobs\CHO.WebJobs.csRfid\Program.cs:line 98

[12/02/2017 17:04:13 > d747a0: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code -532462766

[12/02/2017 17:04:13 > d747a0: SYS INFO] Process went down, waiting for 60 seconds

[12/02/2017 17:04:13 > d747a0: SYS INFO] Status changed to PendingRestart

[12/02/2017 17:05:14 > d747a0: SYS INFO] Run script 'CHO.WebJobs.csRfid.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'

[12/02/2017 17:05:14 > d747a0: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running

[12/02/2017 17:05:28 > d747a0: INFO] Found the following functions:

[12/02/2017 17:05:28 > d747a0: INFO] CHO.WebJobs.csRfid.GPOFunctions.ProcessQueueMessage

[12/02/2017 17:05:28 > d747a0: INFO] CHO.WebJobs.csRfid.GPOFunctions.ProcessTimer

[12/02/2017 17:05:29 > d747a0: INFO] Singleton lock acquired (5d3cc9c4e92841579c4df47db66e5bfc/CHO.WebJobs.csRfid.GPOFunctions.ProcessTimer.Listener)

[12/02/2017 17:05:29 > d747a0: INFO] Function 'CHO.WebJobs.csRfid.GPOFunctions.ProcessTimer' initial status: Last='2017-12-02T16:54:06.7331501+00:00', Next='2017-12-02T16:55:06.7331501+00:00'

[12/02/2017 17:05:29 > d747a0: INFO] Function 'CHO.WebJobs.csRfid.GPOFunctions.ProcessTimer' is past due on startup. Executing now.

[12/02/2017 17:05:32 > d747a0: INFO] Executing 'GPOFunctions.ProcessQueueMessage' (Reason='New ServiceBus message detected on 'tprfid/Subscriptions/subRfidUat'.', Id=15bc1f92-4def-4ba2-ba96-5c2f510ee933)

[12/02/2017 17:05:32 > d747a0: INFO] Singleton lock acquired (5d3cc9c4e92841579c4df47db66e5bfc/CHO.WebJobs.csRfid.GPOFunctions.ProcessQueueMessage)

[12/02/2017 17:05:33 > d747a0: INFO] Executing 'GPOFunctions.ProcessTimer' (Reason='Timer fired at 2017-12-02T17:05:29.9786228+00:00', Id=3d6dc09b-82fb-41ae-a8d6-9d140af14945)

[12/02/2017 17:05:33 > d747a0: INFO] Singleton lock acquired (5d3cc9c4e92841579c4df47db66e5bfc/CHO.WebJobs.csRfid.GPOFunctions.ProcessTimer)

[12/02/2017 17:05:33 > d747a0: INFO] 12/2/2017 5:05:33 PM - Rfid processing started for Message Id 3286814.

[12/02/2017 17:05:55 > d747a0: ERR ] 

[12/02/2017 17:05:55 > d747a0: ERR ] Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

[12/02/2017 17:05:55 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)

[12/02/2017 17:05:55 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalBind(EndPoint localEP)

[12/02/2017 17:05:55 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnectEx(EndPoint remoteEP, Boolean flowContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)

[12/02/2017 17:05:55 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UnsafeBeginConnect(EndPoint remoteEP, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)

[12/02/2017 17:05:55 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)

[12/02/2017 17:05:55 > d747a0: ERR ]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

[12/02/2017 17:05:55 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

[12/02/2017 17:05:55 > d747a0: ERR ]    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndGetResponse[T](IAsyncResult getResponseResult) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line 284

[12/02/2017 17:05:55 > d747a0: ERR ]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

[12/02/2017 17:05:55 > d747a0: ERR ]    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndExecuteAsync[T](IAsyncResult result) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line 50

[12/02/2017 17:05:55 > d747a0: ERR ]    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue.CloudQueue.EndExists(IAsyncResult asyncResult) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Queue\CloudQueue.cs:line 994

[12/02/2017 17:05:55 > d747a0: ERR ]    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.AsyncExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1`1.<CreateCallback>b__0(IAsyncResult ar) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Util\AsyncExtensions.cs:line 66

[12/02/2017 17:05:55 > d747a0: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

[12/02/2017 17:05:55 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

[12/02/2017 17:05:55 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

[12/02/2017 17:05:55 > d747a0: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Queues.Listeners.QueueListener.<ExecuteAsync>d__21.MoveNext()

[12/02/2017 17:05:55 > d747a0: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

[12/02/2017 17:05:55 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

[12/02/2017 17:05:55 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

[12/02/2017 17:05:55 > d747a0: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Timers.TaskSeriesTimer.<RunAsync>d__14.MoveNext()

[12/02/2017 17:05:55 > d747a0: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

[12/02/2017 17:05:55 > d747a0: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Timers.WebJobsExceptionHandler.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<OnUnhandledExceptionAsync>b__0()

[12/02/2017 17:05:55 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)

[12/02/2017 17:05:55 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)

[12/02/2017 17:05:55 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)

[12/02/2017 17:05:55 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)

[12/02/2017 17:05:55 > d747a0: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

[12/02/2017 17:05:55 > d747a0: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code -532462766

[12/02/2017 17:05:55 > d747a0: SYS INFO] Process went down, waiting for 60 seconds

[12/02/2017 17:05:55 > d747a0: SYS INFO] Status changed to PendingRestart
```

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this issue? I'm experiencing something very similar, but always failing - https://stackoverflow.com/q/49551078/250254

Answer (score 2):

I see that you're getting an exception trying to open a Socket to talk to Windows Storage. I'm guessing that the intermittent problem you're experiencing is due to hitting up against the outbound connection limit for an Azure Web App. To fix this, try scaling up to a higher plan.

Comment: Thanks - I've just upgraded the service plan.  I'll wait and see how it goes :)

Comment: Note, were getting a bunch of service bus time out exceptions too (azure web job not able to connect to azure service bus)

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have any CORS enabled for your Storage account? If there is CORS, then it would be accessible only from the whitelisted domains.

Comment: +1. This just solved an issue with a queue trigger Azure Function that suddenly stopped working due to a misconfigured CORS setting.

Answer (score 1):

We were recently facing a similar issue with one of our web job which was working fine earlier but suddenly stopped working. Web job tried to restart every minute but it was getting failed with the error message **Invalid storage account *ABStorage*. Please make sure your credentials are correct.** Web job remained in Pending Restart status. Upon investigation, we found out that the storage connection string is perfectly fine while there is some bug in Azure storage SDK due to which CORS rules configured on Azure portal against the storage account were not being interpreted correctly. In the Azure portal, we had only 1 CORS rule on Azure storage having all allowed HTTP methods selected. We updated the CORS rule on the storage account to have one HTTP method per domain and the web job was able to start immediately.
[image: Multiple HTTP Methods in One row]
[image: One HTTP method per row]