# Azure WebJobs using .NET Core 2 failing with "Invalid storage account"

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-storage, azure-webjobs

Following Matt Roberts excellent step-by-step article [Azure WebJobs in .NET Core 2 (with DI and configuration)](https://matt-roberts.me/azure-webjobs-in-net-core-2-with-di-and-configuration/) I've created a solution that deploys without issue (using Visual Studio 2017), but fails with a "Invalid storage account" exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid storage account 'mywebjobsstorage'. Please make sure your credentials are correct. ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Shared.Protocol.ServiceProperties> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobClient.GetServicePropertiesAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken)'.
```

I can see that the AzureWebJobsDashboard and AzureWebJobsStorage environment variables must be getting picked up as the error explicitly names the AccountName used in the connection string.

I've tried two variations with the storage connection string with the same result:

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=mywebjobsstorage;AccountKey=********

DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=mywebjobsstorage;AccountKey=********;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net
```

Any ideas what the issue might be?

Here's the full exception log in case it contains any other clues, or I'm being misdirected:

```
[03/29/2018 07:52:43 > d801c3: SYS INFO] Status changed to Initializing
[03/29/2018 07:52:48 > d801c3: SYS INFO] Run script 'run.cmd' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[03/29/2018 07:52:48 > d801c3: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[03/29/2018 07:52:48 > d801c3: INFO] 
[03/29/2018 07:52:48 > d801c3: INFO] D:\local\Temp\jobs\triggered\MyWebJobs\uoyrr1m3.5sq>dotnet MyWebJobs.dll 
[03/29/2018 07:52:50 > d801c3: ERR ] 
[03/29/2018 07:52:50 > d801c3: ERR ] Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid storage account 'mywebjobsstorage'. Please make sure your credentials are correct. ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Shared.Protocol.ServiceProperties> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobClient.GetServicePropertiesAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken)'.
[03/29/2018 07:52:50 > d801c3: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Storage.Blob.StorageBlobClient.GetServicePropertiesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[03/29/2018 07:52:50 > d801c3: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.DefaultStorageCredentialsValidator.<ValidateCredentialsAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()
[03/29/2018 07:52:50 > d801c3: ERR ]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[03/29/2018 07:52:50 > d801c3: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.DefaultStorageCredentialsValidator.<ValidateCredentialsAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()
[03/29/2018 07:52:50 > d801c3: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[03/29/2018 07:52:50 > d801c3: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
[03/29/2018 07:52:50 > d801c3: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
[03/29/2018 07:52:50 > d801c3: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
[03/29/2018 07:52:50 > d801c3: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.DefaultStorageCredentialsValidator.<ValidateCredentialsAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
[03/29/2018 07:52:50 > d801c3: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[03/29/2018 07:52:50 > d801c3: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
[03/29/2018 07:52:50 > d801c3: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
[03/29/2018 07:52:50 > d801c3: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
[03/29/2018 07:52:50 > d801c3: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.DefaultStorageAccountProvider.<CreateAndValidateAccountAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
[03/29/2018 07:52:50 > d801c3: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[03/29/2018 07:52:51 > d801c3: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
[03/29/2018 07:52:51 > d801c3: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
[03/29/2018 07:52:51 > d801c3: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
[03/29/2018 07:52:51 > d801c3: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.DefaultStorageAccountProvider.<TryGetAccountAsync>d__25.MoveNext()
[03/29/2018 07:52:51 > d801c3: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[03/29/2018 07:52:51 > d801c3: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
[03/29/2018 07:52:51 > d801c3: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
[03/29/2018 07:52:51 > d801c3: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
[03/29/2018 07:52:51 > d801c3: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.JobHostConfigurationExtensions.<CreateJobHostContextAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
[03/29/2018 07:52:51 > d801c3: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[03/29/2018 07:52:51 > d801c3: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
[03/29/2018 07:52:51 > d801c3: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
[03/29/2018 07:52:51 > d801c3: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
[03/29/2018 07:52:51 > d801c3: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost.<InitializeHostAsync>d__44.MoveNext()
[03/29/2018 07:52:51 > d801c3: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[03/29/2018 07:52:51 > d801c3: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
[03/29/2018 07:52:51 > d801c3: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
[03/29/2018 07:52:51 > d801c3: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
[03/29/2018 07:52:51 > d801c3: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost.<StartAsyncCore>d__25.MoveNext()
[03/29/2018 07:52:51 > d801c3: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[03/29/2018 07:52:51 > d801c3: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
[03/29/2018 07:52:51 > d801c3: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
[03/29/2018 07:52:51 > d801c3: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
[03/29/2018 07:52:51 > d801c3: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost.Start()
[03/29/2018 07:52:51 > d801c3: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost.RunAndBlock()
[03/29/2018 07:52:51 > d801c3: ERR ]    at MyWebJobs.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\!Projects\SomeProject\src\MyWebJobs\Program.cs:line 30
[03/29/2018 07:52:51 > d801c3: SYS INFO] Status changed to Failed
[03/29/2018 07:52:51 > d801c3: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code -532462766
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there was either a bug in either of these NuGet packages:

- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions

I was using v2.2.0 of these packages, but they appear to have a bug. Swapping these for v3 beta pre-releases of the NuGet packages without any code changes resolved the issue.

**Update**

Only v3+ is supported on .NET Core - https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1649#issuecomment-377633805

Answer (score 0):

We were recently facing a similar issue with one of our web job which was working fine earlier but suddenly stopped working. Web job tried to restart every minute but it was getting failed with the error message **Invalid storage account *ABStorage*. Please make sure your credentials are correct.** Web job remained in **Pending Restart** status. Upon investigation, we found out that the storage connection string is perfectly fine while there is some bug in Azure storage SDK due to which CORS rules configured on Azure portal against the storage account were not being interpreted correctly. In the Azure portal, we had only 1 CORS rule on Azure storage having all allowed HTTP methods selected.
[image: All 7 HTTP method in single row]
We updated the CORS rule on the storage account to have one HTTP method per domain and the web job was able to start immediately.
[image: Only one HTTP method in a row]